# Performance implications of nginx traffic mirroring?

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, proxy, load-balancing

Planning to use Nginx [Mirror](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_mirror_module.html) module to copy the traffic to other server. Wanted to see if there are any performance implication of doing this ?

Like what if the mirror server is buggy or too slow ?

Thanks for any help in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There could be chances of performance impact on prod server if you are running both together. For suppose running socket connection and both are online which might leads to latency or another issue for prod server also.

Forum has few unanswered ticket : https://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,281042,281042

Comment: Related threads 

- https://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,277070,277074#msg-277074

- https://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,281042,281069#msg-281069

- https://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,281042,281069#msg-281069